# Kotlin: store any type of function reference in a variable

Tags: kotlin

Is it possible to have a variable that can holds any type function.

Like :

```
    fun method1(par: Boolean){}
    fun method2(par: Boolean) : Int{return 1}
    fun method3(par: Boolean, par2: Boolean) : Int{return 1}

    var funtionHolder : ((Any)->Any) ?= null  //What should I write here?? so to hold any type of function

   fun method4(){
        .........
        funtionHolder = ::method1  //getting compile time error
        .........
        funtionHolder = ::method2  //getting compile time error
        .........
        funtionHolder = ::method3  //getting compile time error
    }
```

After holding the function_reference I need to invoke it later. So I need to holds it parameter type and state also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hold them in a [`KFunction<Any>`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-function/index.html) or its superclass [`KCallable<Any>`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-callable/index.html) because you know nothing about the parameter list and nothing about the return type, so you have to go to something that can reference at that level of abstraction.  These instances can then be invoked more generically using the `call()` or `callBy()` methods.  (*this requires the `kotlin-reflect` dependency*).  To do something safer and to call like a normal function you'd have to cast back to the specific function type later.

If you want to avoid this, you'll need to unify your signatures to something you can point to with another function type (i.e. `KFunction1` or `KFunction2`).  Otherwise how you'll call this, what you'll do with it will be up to you at this point because you erased all the information that allows you to easily call the function.

```
val functionHolder1: KFunction<Any> = ::method1 // success!
val functionHolder2: KFunction<Any> = ::method2 // success!
val functionHolder3: KFunction<Any> = ::method3 // success!
```

You can then make a `DeferredFunction` class to hold these along with parameters you want to later pass, and then invoke it whenever in the future.

```
class DeferredFunction(val function: KFunction<Any>, vararg val params: Any?) {
    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    operator fun <T> invoke(): T {
        return function.call(params) as T
    }
}

fun whatever(name: String, age: Int): String {
    return "$name of age $age"
}

val functionHolder = DeferredFunction(::whatever, "Fred", 65)

println(functionHolder<String>()) // "Fred of age 65"
```

You do not need the generic return type on the `invoke` function and could just make it return `Any` or call it as `functionHolder<Any>()` but it is nice if you know what to expect for the return.  You can decide what to do there based on your actual use case.  Also no need to special case for no parameters, just don't pass any, i.e. `DeferredFunction(::otherFunc)`

Comment: Wow!! It works. 
Yes it needs the dependency kotlin-reflect.
I used spread operator and vararg for holding the function state.

Answer (score 0):

With reference from Jayson's answer, added extra code to hold the state of the function by using **vararg** and **spread operator(*)**.

```
    var functionHolder: KFunction<Any> ?= null
    var paramsHolder : Array<out Any?> ?= null

    fun hold(functionReference : KFunction<Any>, vararg args : Any?) {
        this.functionHolder = functionReference
        this.paramsHolder = args
    }

    fun release() {
        if (functionHolder != null) {
            if (paramsHolder != null) {
                functionHolder?.call(*paramsHolder!!)
            } else {
                functionHolder?.call()
            }
        }
    }
```

......

```
    fun method3(par: Boolean, par2: Boolean) : Int{return 1}
```

......

```
    hold(::method3, true, false)
    release()//it works
```

Comment: Shanki, I updated my answer to do something similar but more encapsulated, please take a look at that.  Less answers, and a more complete single answer is always better :-)

Answer (score -1):

No. Kotlin is static typed language and doesn't allow this. Else what happens when this is called?

```
functionHolder->invoke(3)
```

and when functionHolder is assigned a lamda that doesn't take parameter?